# Which `JsonInclude.Include` value does Jackson use if it has not been configured explicitly?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, default-value

The documentation on `JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS` reads:

> Pseudo-value used to indicate that the higher-level defaults make sense, to avoid overriding inclusion value. For example, if returned for a property this would use defaults for the class that contains property, if any defined; and if none defined for that, then global serialization inclusion details.

So what does this global inclusion value default to?

Also, can this default be relied on, or is it something that is frequently changed by other frameworks, e. g. Spring, during confiduration?

Answer (score -1):

Copying the text of your first question from the title of the post:

> Which JsonInclude.Include value does Jackson use if it has not been
> configured explicitly?

It uses the `ObjectMapper` configuration settings that are equals to `JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS` for *content* and *value* fields (map entries and classes) :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Value value = objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultPropertyInclusion();
System.out.println(value); //<-- JsonInclude.Value(value=USE_DEFAULTS,content=USE_DEFAULTS)
```

Your second question:

> Also, can this default be relied on, or is it something that is
> frequently changed by other frameworks, e. g. Spring, during
> confiduration?

For Spring framework the initial configuration starts with the same values previously said, so unless you explicitely set it to new values or create a custom `ObjectMapper` you can rely on it.

Comment: The first sentence of the question literally mentions `JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS`.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. Answering that `JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS` is the default value for `JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS` does not provide any useful information.